# req.body is empty{ } at server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I had a problem in req.body at server as i received req.body as {} empty, here is the code at service

```js
addEmployeeCollection(addArray: EmployeeSchema) {
  let url: string = Constants.DOMAIN + Constants.CREATE_EMPLOYEE_ROUTE;
  console.log('addArray at employee service', addArray)
  var body = addArray;
  return this._httpService.post(url, body).map(res => res.json()).catch(this._errorHandler);
}
```

this._httpService.post(url, body) will go to the interceptor, there the http.post method returned, here is the interceptor code,

```js
post(url: string, body: Object, options ? : RequestOptionsArgs): Observable < Response > {
  this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let token = localStorage.getItem('realtoken');
  console.log('http token', token);
  if (typeof url === 'string') {
    if (!options) {
      options = {
        headers: this.headers
      };
    }
    options.headers.set('Authorization', ` ${token}`);
  }
  return super.post(url, body, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
}
```

now here the request payload at headers contains the information,

[image]

The response from the server side is

```
{"__v":0,"_id":"58ba4969ed69821fd6f7e573"}// details of employee is not saved
```

here the server side code

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

//schema-models
var employeeCollection = require('../../model/employee.model.js');


router.post('/new', function(req, res) {

  var employee_data = req.body;
  console.log('req.body=====> ', req.body)
  var addcontent = new employeeCollection(employee_data);
  console.log('addcontent--->', addcontent);
  addcontent.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log('data', data);
      res.json(data);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

At terminal, `req.body=====>  {}`, the employee details are sent correctly in the request, but at server side am getting as empty req.body
As a beginner to this concepts,i could not figure out where i am getting wrong, please help me out

Comment: your token setting part of the code seems a bit odd..which `localstorage` are you using?

Comment: @suraj i am using the local storage of the browser

Comment: Dont know if this is the cause but generally it is  `    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer  ${token});`

Comment: @suraj i tried but it didnot work

Comment: try `this._httpService.post(url, JSON.stringify(body))`

Comment: Where (and how) exactly is `router` added to `app` in your server-side code?